# is "sound" an adjective for "counsel"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

is "sound" an adjective for "counsel"?

> In some ways Kane's position is hopelessly illogical. He was on most
>   intimate and affectionate terms with the mother and the two girls,
>   although if words have any meaning he thought them to be swindlers
>   living on the credulity of the public. "Kiss Katie for me," he says,
>   and he continually sends love to the mother. Already, young as they
>   were, he had a glimpse of the alcoholic danger to which they were
>   exposed by late hours and promiscuous company. "Tell Katie to drink no
>   champagne, and do you follow the same advice," said he. **It was sound
>   counsel,** and it would have been well for themselves and for the
>   movement if they had both followed it; but again we must remember
>   their inexperienced youth and the constant temptations.

I searched the dictionary but I thought that it must be "a sound counsel" not "sound counsel", I knew that "sound" is an adjective. it was a little ambiguous for me because of the proposition "a".

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Comment: Thanks for posting as a new question.  Did you also take my advice and refer to a dictionary? If so then please edit to tell us what you found out.

Comment: @James K yes. i searched the dictionary but i thought that it must be "a sound counsel" not "sound counsel", i knew that "sound" is an adjective. it was a little ambiguous for me because of the proposition "a".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "sound" is an adjective modifying "counsel". This is the definition:
[Merriam-Webster "sound"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sound)
3a:  free from error, fallacy, or misapprehension
 e.g., sound advice, sound reasoning

Answer (score 1):

The word "counsel" means "advice" and is non-countable.  Therefore we don't use "A".

Sound is an adjective, and has its usual dictionary meaning.